# Exception Handling in Rails Fragment Caching

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

I was trying to handle the exception if the Memcachier server is down, but it seems that is not happening.

I am using a code snippet in the Rails view; basically, there is a service that would return the data and keep that in a Javascript variable because I need to process that data through JS, so instead of calling the service every time, we cached (Fragment Caching) that data.

We are using Memcachier in production, but sometimes the server will not be reachable; in that case, I am trying to get the data directly.

*views/orders.html.erb*

```
<script>

var orders =
    <% cache_key = "outlet_#{@location_id}_data"
    begin
      cache(cache_key, skip_digest: true, expires_in: 5.days) do

        response = Outlet::V1::Orders.new(id: @outlet_id).send!
        if response.success? %>
          <%= response.data.to_json.html_safe %>
        <% else %>
          '[]'
        <% end
      end %>;
    <% rescue StandardError => e
      Rails.logger.error "Server is not reachable, #{e.message}"
      **Take data directly through service**
    end %>

</script>
```

Is this the correct way to handle it?